# dares-qt how to install

Tags: dvd, qt

I have tried to reading one my old dvd however when i try to mount it, i get the following error :

```
umut@DESKTOP-PC:/$ sudo udisks --mount /dev/sr1 / udisks --unmount /dev/sr1 / udisks --eject /dev/sr1
Mount failed: Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: /dev/sr1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sr1: can't read superblock
```

So i guess that dvd is scratched and thats why unable to be mounted.I have searched that i can rescue the dvd using dares-qt utility however i am unable to install this utility.I am getting the following error when i try installing its package :

```
umut@DESKTOP-PC:/$ sudo apt-get install dares-qt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dares-qt
```

How can i solve this ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

2 methods to find out what you did wrong:

> **Local search on "dares" tells you the package name is "dares" and not "dares-qt"**

```
sudo apt-cache search dares
dares - rescue files from damaged CDs and DVDs (ncurses-interface)
```

> **On-line search in the packages list**

It seems that the software got renamed after Ubuntu Precise and is now called `dares`

- [package dares-qt](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/dares-qt) is in universe Lucid and Precise. No other versions.
- [package dares](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/dares) is in Universe. Link goes to the trusty version.

"universe" is enabled by default so drop the "-qt" from your command.

---

**Executing from my system installs it**

```
sudo apt-get install dares
[sudo] password for rinzwind: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gtk2-engines-pixbuf libboost-program-options1.55.0 libcrypt-blowfish-perl
  libcrypt-cbc-perl libcrypt-rijndael-perl libexpect-perl
  libgtk2-ex-simple-list-perl libgtk2-gladexml-perl libio-stty-perl
  libkeybinder0 libnet-arp-perl libnet-pcap-perl libnet-proxy-perl
  libossp-uuid-perl libossp-uuid16 linux-headers-3.16.0-22
  linux-headers-3.16.0-22-generic linux-image-3.16.0-22-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-22-generic python-keybinder
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dares
```

...

---

This installs the software itself.

If you want the GUI... you could try to install the precise version (http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/dares-qt/download download the deb and try to install it with USC by doubleclicking it).

---

**Alternatives**

- [dvdisaster](http://dvdisaster.net/en/index.html). GUI. Problem: Error correction data must be created before the medium fails, preferably at the same time the medium is written.
- [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/). command line from the looks of it.
- [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/). command line.

Software to rescue files mostly focusses on getting those files. So they tend to be command line.

Comment: thank you for fast reply.i have installed "dares" already however i can't get its graphical interface.. was thinking need to install dares-qt for the graphical version.Graphic version of this utility is no more available ? Or can you suggest an alternative for that if it has no graphical interface anymore ?

Comment: Package Installer gives this error: Error: Dependency is not satisfiable:libqt3-mt (»=3:3.3.8-b)

Comment: That is a showstopped then. I added some alternatives but they are all command line. I have not found a gui (yet).

Comment: I ran in to this in another project that dropped out of repo...  also Qt based.  That drop-out timeline on the other project indicated that the project was never updated beyond Qt3 (which means when qt5 hit edge and qt4 hit standard - it dropped out of repo)

Comment: thank you for your help.i have run the command line version but get the following error: "no medium found on /dev/sr1" . it means it cant read the disc ?